# grabbing an ID from string

Tags: python

I have a string where I'd like to grab the "id" number `12079500908`. I am trying to use `ast.literal_eval` but received a `ValueError: malformed string`. Is there any other way to get the `id` number from the string below?

```
doc_request = urllib2.Request("https://api.box.com/2.0/search?query=SEARCHTERMS", headers=doc_headers)
doc_response = urllib2.urlopen(doc_request)
view_doc_response = doc_response.read()
doc_dict=ast.literal_eval(view_doc_response)
```

**Edit**
Output:

```
view_doc_response = '{"total_count":1,"entries":[{"type":"file","id":"12079500908","sequence_id":"1","etag":"1","sha1":"6887169228cab0cfb341059194bc980e1be8ad90","name":"file.pdf","description":"","size":897838,"path_collection":{"total_count":2,"entries":[{"type":"folder","id":"0","sequence_id":null,"etag":null,"name":"All Files"},{"type":"folder","id":"1352745576","sequence_id":"0","etag":"0","name":"Patient Files"}]},"created_at":"2013-12-03T10:23:30-08:00","modified_at":"2013-12-03T11:17:52-08:00","trashed_at":null,"purged_at":null,"content_created_at":"2013-12-03T10:23:30-08:00","content_modified_at":"2013-12-03T11:17:52-08:00","created_by":{"type":"user","id":"20672372","name":"name","login":"email"},"modified_by":{"type":"user","id":"206732372","name":"name","login":"email"},"owned_by":{"type":"user","id":"206737772","name":"name","login":"email"},"shared_link":{"url":"https:\\/\\/www.box.net\\/s\\/ymfslf1phfqiw65bunjg","download_url":"https:\\/\\/www.box.net\\/shared\\/static\\/ymfslf1phfqiw65bunjg.pdf","vanity_url":null,"is_password_enabled":false,"unshared_at":null,"download_count":0,"preview_count":0,"access":"open","permissions":{"can_download":true,"can_preview":true}},"parent":{"type":"folder","id":"1352745576","sequence_id":"0","etag":"0","name":"Patient Files"},"item_status":"active"}],"limit":30,"offset":0}'
```

calling `doc_dict` gives:

```
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: Can you show the exact line of code you are using?

Comment: Did you notice the "..." at the end? Your source data is broken.

Comment: Are you able to get the full string instead of this truncated one?

Comment: Ok I'll post the full string. And I will post the exact code I am using.

Comment: Where did this string come from? Was it generated by `repr`? If not, you shouldn't use `literal_eval` on it. (And if it _was_ generated by `repr`, but you're writing the code that generates it… don't use `repr` and `literal_eval`…)

Comment: See [repr + eval = bad idea](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/11/repr-eval-bad-idea.html) and [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the tutorial for more on why something like JSON is a much better choice.

Comment: If this is/was JSON just ``x = loads(s)`` and ``x["id"]``

Comment: Posted the full string and my code. I have heard `requests` is better than `urllib2` but I have not used it yet. Would it be simplier to use `requests`?

Comment: @DjangoNovice: No. `requests` is definitely simpler for some things—POSTing file attachments, maintaining cookies, etc.—but if the `urllib2` part of your code is working and simple enough that you understand it, `requests` is not going to make it any more simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval` is for parsing valid Python syntax, what you have is JSON.  Valid JSON looks a lot like Python syntax except that JSON can contain `null`, `true`, and `false` which are mapped to `None`, `True`, and `False` in Python when passed through a JSON decoder.  You can use [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) for this.  The code might look something like this:

```
import json
doc_dict = json.loads(view_doc_response)
first_id = doc_dict['entries'][0]['id']  # with your data, should be 12079500908
```

Note that this assumes that you manually added the `...` at the end of the string, presumably after shortening it.  If that `...` is actually in your code as well then you have invalid JSON and you will need to do some processing before it will work.

Comment: Thanks .. you did it. I didn't know I had a JSON. I thought it was just a string. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @DjangoNovice: If it was "just a string", why would you expect `literal_eval` to be able to handle it? It has to be in _some_ format, and the first key to handling any format always has to be finding out what format it is…